# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'

Tags: python, discord, attributes, bots, key

```
    import discord
    import requests
    import json
    import random
    from replit import db


    client = discord.Client()

    sad_words = ["sad", "depressed" , "unhappy", "angry" , "miserable" , "depressing"]

    starter_encouragements = [ "Cheer up!", "Hang in there." , "You are a great person / 
     bot!"]

    def get_quote():
       response = requests.get("https://zenquotes.io/api/random")
       json_data = json.loads(response.text)
       quote = json_data[0]['q'] + "-" + json_data[0]['a']
       return(quote)

    def update_encouragements(encouraging_message):
        if "encouragements" in db.keys():
           encouragements = db["encouragements"]
           encouragements.appen(encouraging_message)
            db["encouragements"] = encouragements
          else:
              db["encouragements"] = [encouraging_message]

       def delete_encouragement(index):
          encouragements = db["encouragements"]
      if len(encouragements) > index:
         del encouragements[index]
        db["encouragements"] = encouragements

   TOKEN = XXX

          @client.event
     async def on_ready():
       print ('we have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


  @client.event
      async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    msg = message.content

    if msg.startswith('inspire'):
        quote = get_quote()
        await message.channel.send(quote)

    
    options = starter_encouragements
    if "encouragements" in db.keys():
          options = options + db["encouragements"]

    if any(word in msg for word in sad_words) :
        await message.channel.send(random.choice(options))

    if msg.startswith("$new"):
        encouraging_message = msg.split("$new " ,1)[1]
        update_encouragements(encouraging_message)
        await message.channel.send("New encouraging message added.")

    if msg.startswith("del"):
        encouragements = []
        if "encouragements"   in db.keys():
            index = msg.split("$del" , 1)[1]
            delete_encouragement(index)
            encouragements = db["encouragements"]
        await message.channel.send(encouragements)


        client.run(TOKEN)
```

'''
This a discord bot , the error i am getting is 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'.It's an attribute error. I hope i could get some help. (About me , just a beginner trying new things bumped into this and loved it ) pls drop some tips too for making more efficient bots
'''

error is written below

-------->error:   ' if "encouragements" in db.keys():  '
'  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no
attribute 'keys'   '

Comment: maybe first check `if db is not None:`

Comment: it means that db is None. probably an issue with importing it. make sure you're importing db correctly first.

Comment: you import `db` from `replit` - how do you create `db` in this file? maybe you create `db = None` or you run some `db = some_function()` but this functiond doesn't have `return db`

Comment: can you pls explain it by telling specific codes to add or remove? @furas

Comment: your real problem is inside `replit.py` which you didn't show - so I have no idea what is the problem and how to fix it.

Comment: No listen replit is an online IDE. i am importing db from replit as given in a video over you tube. I am using replit database to store user submitted messages , idk how i can use vs code database instead. @furas

Comment: I don't know what database has `replit`. `VSCODE` doesn't have any database - it is only IDE and it has nothing to do with database. Normally you have install database on your own and install Python module for this database. Only module for SQLite is installed with Python.

Comment: I created new project on `replit` and I has no problem to use `db`. I can't reproduce your problem. Maybe you have something more and you assign `None` to `db`

Comment: How to not assign none to db? Can you pls comprehend?